# alternative for calling a model from view in this situation

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I know we are suppose to call models from controller not the view but i'm in a situation that i have to do this

here it is :

I have a bloging script and in each user home page i want to show 10 posts and 5 comments for each post

So my controller looks something like

```
function get_posts($user_id){

   $blog_model = $this->load->model('bloging');
   $posts      = $blog_model->get_user_posts();
   $this->load->view('blog' , $posts )
}
```

Each post could have many comments 
so i have to get them too

So in my view i have

```
foreach($posts->result() as  $p ){

  echo $p->comment;

 /// getting comments
  $comment_model = $this->load->model('comments');
  $co = $comment_model->get_post_comments($p->id);
  foreach($co as $co )
   echo $co->comment;
  //////


}
```

I now this doesn't work like this as i have to use a helper or library or use a static method in model to do this( i'm using codeigniter , it might be different for other frame works )

But what  alternative do i have  ?

I can do this in controller , after getting posts use a foreach loop and get each post comments , put all comments in a 2d array(`$c_array[post_id][it's comments array]`)

Send them to the view with posts and in the view for each post look into the array for it's comments and .......

But it seams complicated , redundant and slower

i already have 4 joins on the post query and 2 joins on the comments query it would be 7 if i join these two

and also there is different limit for select in two query 
I'm fairly new to mvc . what is the right approach in this kind of situations ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would have a method on the `post` model to fetch comments for that post. Additionally i would normally have a method to make sure Comments are joined to the posts so you dont issue a comments query for every post.

Comment: yeah but i already have 4 joins on the post query and 2 joins on the comments query it would be 7 joins if i these two . also there is different limits for selecting comments and post ( sorry i should have mention this )

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have created your own MVC system for this, so I don't know how you would implement this. I use Zend Framework, so I can tell you how I would do it using that.

There is nothing inherently wrong with accessing models from the view, so long as it is read only access, but it is good to keep as much code as possible out of your view scripts. To this end, in your situation, I would use a [view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) and [writing your own view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom) is quite simple in ZF. I will leave it to you to adapt this to your MVC if you wish to use this method.

This means you can abstract the code you need to get a list of comments out of the view script and replace it with something like:-

```
echo $this->getComments($messageID);
```